# webcoreglue: Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm developing an application with phonegap cordova 2.7.0, i have an event click binded to an image like this

```
$("#actu_gauge").live("click",function() {
alert('aaaa');
idExercice =  window.sessionStorage['exercie_selected'];
chargeIndicateurOC(idExercice, 1);

// capturePhoto();
});
```

The image is over another image with negative margin-top.
When i click to the image i got this error : `webcoreglue: Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found in phonegap`
Any one can help?

Comment: Can you debug idExercice or pirnt idExcercice value. Because you write use ['exercice_selected'] you must write use ( ) like this window.sessionStorage('excercie_selrcted') not use [ ] but use ( ). I hope can help you.

Comment: read this article http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/domstorage.shtml, the sessionStorage should be used with []